# Auto increment in php myadmin is giving weird numbers

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database for contacts and Phpmyadmin is giving me weird ids. Sometimes Ids start from  67000 sth and sometimes from 7. In my operations-->auto_increment is set to 676503. I try to change it and press go. It does not change.It keeps on giving me the same number. Also, when I click to show the data, when Ids and contacts are displayed, a column named rows is displayed. The column has only the value 1 for all contacts, as if all contacts are in row 1. 
How can I fix this?

Edit: 
contacts

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `date_entered` datetime default NULL,
 `date_modified` datetime default NULL,
 `modified_user_id` char(36) default NULL,
 `created_by` char(36) default NULL,
 `description` text,
 `deleted` tinyint(1) default '0',
 `assigned_user_id` int(36) NOT NULL,
 `salutation` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `title` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `department` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `do_not_call` tinyint(1) default '0',
 `phone_home` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `phone_mobile` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `phone_work` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `phone_other` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `phone_fax` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `primary_address_street` varchar(150) default NULL,
 `primary_address_city` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `primary_address_state` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `primary_address_postalcode` varchar(20) default NULL,
 `primary_address_country` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `alt_address_street` varchar(150) default NULL,
 `alt_address_city` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `alt_address_state` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `alt_address_postalcode` varchar(20) default NULL,
 `alt_address_country` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `assistant` varchar(75) default NULL,
 `assistant_phone` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `lead_source` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `reports_to_id` char(36) default NULL,
 `birthdate` date default NULL,
 `campaign_id` char(36) default NULL,
 `age` datetime default NULL,
 `days_old` int(6) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_3` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_4` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_5` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_6` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_7` (`id`),
 KEY `idx_cont_last_first` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`deleted`),
 KEY `idx_contacts_del_last` (`deleted`,`last_name`),
 KEY `idx_cont_del_reports` (`deleted`,`reports_to_id`,`last_name`),
 KEY `idx_reports_to_id` (`reports_to_id`),
 KEY `idx_del_id_user` (`deleted`,`id`,`assigned_user_id`),
 KEY `idx_cont_assigned` (`assigned_user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=676504 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide table shcema. SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name

Comment: Do I write on mysql phpmyadmin this query? 
Please note I have data in my contacts table I do not want to lose.

Comment: Yes you can write this query which show table structure and you can't lose your data

Comment: I added what you asked for. Sorry the sentences are put like this, don't know why..

Comment: When you are insert new record then what is auto_id value, Because I tested it take id=676504

Comment: How can I fix it? I do not know from where did this value come from.

Comment: When you do an insert do you specify a value for id or leave it as NULL.

Comment: I do not touch the id. Isn't it supposed to give me a generated id itself value auto incremented when I add a new contact?

Comment: If you don't specify it, or you specify a value of NULL for it. If you have a value in the INSERT for it then it will use that value (and might well reject the insert with a duplicate key if it already exists)